# xamarin securestring equivalent in PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, dependency-injection, portable-class-library, securestring

SecureString is not friendly with PCL.I Know this problem can be worked around using dependency injection But I don't want to do that instead I would like to use something in PCL that would be equivalent to SecureString.

But so far I am not able to find any other class or framework.

Comment: it shouldn't be friendly, that is the point of PCL.  It stops you from taking a dependency that is inappropriate or outright invalid on one of the platform targets you selected.  Yes, like Xamarin, SecureString is only ever secure when you use pinvoke to pass a password to native code.  Any other usage is never secure.  Clearly you need to show us what that looks like to get an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Security.*` is mostly not present in any Portable Class Library profile. You might be able to find this in some of the higher versions of .NET Standard, which provide a much bigger subset of .NET.

You best bet, if you are fixed on using PCL is to use libraries such as PCLCrypto or roll your own code per platform and inject that at runtime.

Comment: PCLCrypto doesn't provide securestring and rolling out our own could be easily broken

Answer (score 1):

You can use the so called [bait-and-switch trick](https://www.facebook.com/planetxamarin/posts/238447239688621).

In this case it means that you need to create one strong named PCL assembly containing an implementation stub of `SecureString`, including those methods and properties of `SecureString` that you intend to use in your application.

For example:

```
namespace System.Security {
  public class SecureString {
    public SecureString() { }
    public int Length { get; }
    public void AppendChar(char c) { }
  }
}
```

It is crucial that the properties and methods you include use the exact same signature as the original class, since you are going to rely on signature equivalence when using this trick. On the other hand, you do not need to provide a functioning implementation, since this will be handled by the built-in `SecureString` on each respective platform.

Next, you need to create one assembly per platform **with the same strong name as the PCL assembly**, simply containing a type forwarding directive to `SecureString`:

```
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(SecureString))]
```

This relies on the fact that even if no PCL profile defines `SecureString`, each respective platform does. So what you are actually doing in the platform specific DLL is to point out the implementation of `SecureString` that you want to use in place of the PCL declaration.

With the PCL and platform specific assemblies in place, and assuming they all share the same name (e.g. *securestring.dll*) and are signed with the same key, you can now use `SecureString` in your implementation.

Assume for example that you have a PCL assembly *foo.Core.dll* that is consumed by the platform specific applications *foo.Windows.dll*, *foo.Android.dll* and *foo.iOS.dll*, and where *foo.Core.dll* uses `SecureString`. Then you should organize your solution like this:

- *foo.Core.dll* should reference the PCL version of *securestring.dll*.
- *foo.Windows.dll* should reference *foo.Core.dll* **and** the Windows version of *securestring.dll*.
- *foo.Android.dll* should reference *foo.Core.dll* **and** the Android version of *securestring.dll*.
- *foo.iOS.dll* should reference *foo.Core.dll* **and** the iOS version of *securestring.dll*.